# Enable item scheduling on a publishing library via SharePoint .NET client API

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, publishing

**Does anybody know how to enable item scheduling on a publishing library via code (.NET Client API)?**

This can be done via the Settings UI for the library in Manage Item Scheduling. However, I can't find a way to enable this using the .NET Client API. It must not be as simple as just setting a property on the List object like EnableModeration = true or EnableVersioning = true. I can't use the Server-Side API because I'm in Office 365 Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

According to Vesa (heading up Patterns and Practices), you can set a property on the list (I believe you actually set it on the List's Root Folder: https://twitter.com/vesajuvonen/status/581498547700387840