# Enabling item scheduling on a publishing library via JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, document-library, jsom

Alright, I'm trying to enable item scheduling similar to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133579/enable-item-scheduling-on-a-publishing-library-via-sharepoint-net-client-api) this post but via JSOM in sharepoint online through a sharepoint Add-in/App. From the web console I've already looked into properties of the list as well as it's root folder and haven't spotted method to do so. I've looked into a [powershell script](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Enable-ItemScheduling-for-Pages-Library-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell) that supposedly is able to do this via a function within the publishing page web, but JSOM's publishing page web doesn't seem to have the function either. Is there any other way or am I just stuck with using powershell post-deployment?